# Are proxies alive check python

Tags: python, json, parsing, python-requests, proxy

I have a dictionary with lot of proxies grouped by `'html'`, `'socks4'`, `'socks5'` (also saved in json file `'proxy.json'` and I need to check if them are valid and check how fast them are(broken ones delete from dictionary).

How can I do this? I'm using requests library

```
cookies = {
    'http': [],
    'socks5':[],
    'socks4':[]
}
```